# What will happen if I use pointer[Index] in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner in C language, and I was wondering what will happen if I write something like this:

```
    int *p;
    int b = 4;
    int a = 3;
    p = &a;
    printf("%d", p[1])
```

I was expecting the result is "4",  however, I got an unexpected result(which is a random number)

I also make experiment below:
[EXP1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8pta.png)
[EXP2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiRZi.png)

It makes me more confused. I would like some explantions, thanks.

Comment: If someone told you to expect 4 as a result, you should stop listening to that person.

Answer (score 3):

`p[1]` points beyond the end of the object to which `p` points. Dereferencing this pointer is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler does not necessarily store objects in the order you define them.

If you handed an assistant a book, a box, and a bottle, and you told them to put the items on a shelf, would you expect they would definitely put them on the shelf in that order? No, they may take whichever one is easiest to manipulate first and put that on the shelf, then another, then another. And they do not care what order you handed them the items if they do not think there is any significance to it.

When you define objects to a compiler, it manages them according to attributes such as size and alignment requirements. And it does not necessarily hold them in the order you define them. It may store them alphabetically in some data structure. Or it may store them in order by a hash code. When it goes to assign memory locations to the items, it may process objects with the strictest alignment requirements first and, within each group, retrieve them either alphabetically or by traversing its own internal data structure.

So, `b` is not necessarily after `a` in memory.

But, even if it were, the C standard does not define the behavior of accessing `p[1]` when `p` points to `a`. This means the compiler, when it is analyzing the **meaning** of your code, as defined by the C standard, can decide that `printf("%d", p[1])` has no meaning and can disregard it. As a consequence, compiler optimization can transform programs in surprising ways.

Comment: Thanks! But what happen to my experiment?

Comment: `b` is not necessarily in memory *at all*.  It could be stored in a register, or even optimized out entirely because its value is never used.

Answer (score -2):

An Interesting thing is you can get 4 when you use clang to compile it(https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/Djiszr0QhNzEzT0OTq5pLQQHE1SqwBrIg7CQFWwUTBDcRyDWGcAuATLVEKLsIKJmmoaSaoqSjUBBtGKtpzVX7/z8A), but it's still an undefined behavior and should not use as expect.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Clang is free to do all kinds of things to what you think are variables from the POV of the language, and a lot of it depends on optimizations and the target architecture.

Comment: So I said it's still an ub.

Comment: You also said "clang does this", but you offer no proof of that. You only showed that a single run of specific code at a specific time on a specific machine and a specific compiler version and certain specific compiler settings did that. UB means that any change to any of those could get have different results.